# Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, checkboxlist

I'm performing E2E testing and trying to select the two check box from this list.

[image: enter image description]

```js
export class SignupPage {

  select_cuisine='.anchor'


  selectcuisine(){
    cy.get(this.select_cuisine.type="checkbox").check('Coffee & Tea')
    
    }
}
```

```js
import { SignupPage } from "./Pages/signup_page"


it.only('Sign up', function () {
  
  signupage.selectcuisine()
})
```

Error message.

[image]

I want to select at least two checkboxes from the list to complete my end-to-end testing flow.

Comment: Your error is pretty clear on what is wrong. You are trying to add a property to a string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `.anchor` is a very useful selector, it's used for formatting and may change or appear on multiple elements. Also, that element is just the label for the list. You would want to select the list header using`.dropdown-check-list`.

```js
export class SignupPage {

  select_cuisine='.dropdown-check-list'

  selectcuisine(){
    cy.get(this.select_cuisine)             // dropdown list
      .find('li:contains("Coffee & Tea")')  // list item required
      .find('[type="checkbox"]')            // find the checkbox
      .check()
    }
}
```

Comment: still showing error message please reivew.

Comment: Try finding the `<li>` instead.